# Want to get width of View(LinearLayout) at Runtime in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, width, android-linearlayout

How can i get the dynamic width of `LinearLayout` at runtime?

I mean, i want to get the width of `LinearLayout` at runtime , when `LinearLayout` visibility is `"GONE"` and `LinearLayout` width is `"match_parent"` in xml layout file.

I can get width using `onGlobalLayoutChangeListener` and `onPreDrawListener` but only if our view(LinearLayout) is already "`VISIBLE"` state, not at `"GONE"` state.

Is here any solution for this problem?

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply fetch a reference to your linearlayout lets call it "ll" and a call to "ll.getWidth()" gives you thewidth in pixels...

Comment: it will not work, i want to get width before View draw

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getMeasuredWidth()` method:

`int width  = yourView.getMeasuredWidth();`

**PS**: Be careful, you need to call it after `onMeasure()` gets executed, otherwise the view size is not yet measured.

Comment: This is only work, if View is VISIBILE, i am asking, is it possible, if View is GONE state, and After get width , View will be displayed , on current requirement.

Comment: If the View is GONE, both the height and width will be 0. So no matter the way you want to use  to get the width, you'll get 0 as result.